# Making SQL server do string manipulations?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make C# code to extract data from a database table and then write it to a CSV file. For some of the columns I want the values to be enclosed in double quotes. I was wondering if it is better to make SQL server do the appending/prepending or make C# code do that ? Would this make my SQL server query slow in all circumstances ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The "enclosing in double quotes" is an **artifact** of CSV.*

The quotes are *not* part of the data and should thus *not* be returned from SQL queries.

Handle the CSV processing - including adding quotes as required - in C#. I recommend using an existing library<sup>1</sup> which will automatically take care of required quoting and other considerations when the data is *written* as CSV.

Some additional reasons why *not* to do this in SQL:

- Prevents the SQL from becoming polluted with unnecessary manipulations.
- Keeps the query generic; it can be used equally as well to source data for HTML or Excel output.
- The client (C#) can trivially quote the field appropriately based on the value. This makes the code "future proof" if a previously unquoted field needs to be quoted for CSV output.
- Naively adding quotes will fail on data that contains quotes.

---

<sup>1</sup> If a proper library cannot be used, for whatever silly restriction, there are various [single-file implementations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp) floating about that can be used as a basis. YMMV.

Comment: What if I am not allowed to use any library ? Btw, I only want to enclose some and NOT ALL fields in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not good at doing programmatic work. It will always slow it down to some degree. Unless it is a quick and dirty "one time" function I would just use it for data access, which it is good at. I don't even do "order by" clauses if I don't have to.